Can boost pool work with virtual base classes? (tree-like use case)
I am implementing a tree like data structure with a node base class and multiple derived classes. I am looking for a memory pool to allocate the various derived nodes with, but also properly destructs all the allocated nodes (as in via their destructors). For context, at some point in the program I want to destroy all the trees I have created hence why I think a memory pool would be a good way to deallocate all memory at once.
Previously I naively used boost::pool<> and allocated the derived classes with it via new (pool.malloc()) ChildNode1(...) before realising the pool had no concept of the data it was storing so naturally their destructors were not called and data with additional allocations like vectors/strings were not being cleaned up.
I looked at using boost::object_pool<Base> however that does not compile as the Base class is virtual. Does boost pools not work with base classes? Is there some way of achieving my use case with boost pools?

What purpose does the pool have if you require the nontrivial destructors to run? Have you considered PolyCollection and Intrusive tree algorithms?

I should have clarified. I have nothing in the destructors - they're all empty. PolyCollections looks promising, thanks for the suggestion

The destructors are still non-trivial if the object contains non-trivial members or bases: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor

I see. I suppose my use case is that I want to allocate any of these derived objects onto some kind of pool that will automatically get cleaned up when the pool goes out of scope.

I don't know anything about boost::pool, but it almost sounds like you need a memory allocator that's taking memory from a "pool", but the deallocator is a no-op. So, you can destruct the C++ containers normally, all destructors get called, but the "delete" on anything allocated from the pool is super-fast, and you just remove the pool as a whole after destroying the containers that you allocated inside. Be careful with shared_ptr, though :-) You could still keep a counter of allocated objects, so you can assert() it's down to 0 at the end.

You can never forgo the destructor unless it's trivial. It sounds a little bit as though you might want all sub-objects colocated in the same buffer. Boost managed_external_buffer could get you there at the cost of everything being made allocator-aware https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html (see some examples in the context of shared memory)
